# @Value working to apply "default value" - When is mandatory ":" and "?:" each one over the other?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

About `@Value` and applying *default values*, assuming that the `host.ipv6` key does **not** exist

Therefore for Spring 6 working with `@Value` and **without** `SpeL` such as:

```
@Value("${host.ipv6:not defined}")
@Value("${host.ipv6?:not defined}")
```

Work by returning for each one `not defined` as expected - it as the *default value*.

Now, because both returns the same

**Question**

- When is mandatory `:` and `?:` each one over the other?

I am assuming there is a special scenario.

**Extra Question**

- What approach was created first? `:` or `?:`

I am assuming the second approach created resolves or does something that the first can't do

**Observation**

As indicated, if `host.ipv6` does **not** exist:

- if is used `@Value("${host.ipv6}")` it returns/uses/works with `${host.ipv6}` as String or raw text instead